# Safari doesn't save cookies on custom https port

Tags: cookies, https, safari

I have a web application that i'm looking to access by https on port 444.

In Safari, when accessing it, my initial request logs me in successfully (i can see the authentication success message in custom HTTP response headers).

But the site does not display successfully, because the request for the CSS file associated with the page fails with Access Denied.

Upon inspection of the headers, i can see that a session is assigned to the first request (for the page, with the Set-Cookie response header), and a new session has been assigned for the CSS request (also with the Set-Cookie response header).  No cookies show up in the Web Inspector.  My assumption is that the cookie from the first request is not being saved and so the server is assigning a new session.

When accessing the site on the standard https port (443), the behavior is as expected, as it is when accessing it on port 444 with Firefox.  I'm on OSX Mountain Lion.

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The site in question is on an intranet only really used by staff, so we've just recommended not using Safari :-/

Comment: I had a similar problem - eventually I realized that the client had disabled cookies